# What happened to the Devel variable syntax info info by double clicking on items?

Tags: 7, debugging

Not long ago I could doubleclick on items like arrays, objects etc in Devel to see the syntax, if I wanted to fetch one value or another for example. That does not work anymore. I have tried using different Jquery versions, from core version up to 2.1. But that's not it.

Anybody?

I am sure this is a very stupid question... but I take my chances. I cannot figure it out.

[image]

Comment: do you check your browser console? is ther any error?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the browser console. No errors. I also tried using different browsers with the same result.

Comment: I'm sure this happened because of JS,

Comment: OK, I will investigate further. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome, hope find it soon